# How to implement Custom Keras Regularizer in TF 2.X?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement custom regularizer function for distributed learning to implement the penalty function as in the equation
[image: From the paper FedProx]

I implemented the above functions as a layer wise regularizer, however it throws me error. Looking forward for the help from the community

```
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package='Custom', name='esgd')
def esgd(w, wt, mu):
    delta = tf.math.square(tf.norm(w-wt))
    rl = (mu/2)*delta
    return rl

def model(w, wt, mu):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu',input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
                                tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
                                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
                                tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
                                tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
                                tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu',  kernel_initializer='ones',kernel_regularizer=esgd(w[0][7],wt[0][7],mu)
),
                                tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
                                tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
                               ])
    return model
```

----- Error -------

```
---> 59        model = init_model(w, wt, mu)
     60 
     61 #       model.set_weights(wei[0])

<ipython-input-5-e0796dd9fa55> in init_model(w, wt, mu)
     11                                 tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
     12                                 tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
---> 13                                 tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu',  kernel_initializer='ones',kernel_regularizer=esgd(w[0][7],wt[0][7],mu)
     14 ),
     15                                 tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py in __init__(self, units, activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, bias_constraint, **kwargs)
   1137     self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
   1138     self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)
-> 1139     self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
   1140     self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)
   1141     self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/regularizers.py in get(identifier)
    313     return identifier
    314   else:
--> 315     raise ValueError('Could not interpret regularizer identifier:', identifier)

ValueError: ('Could not interpret regularizer identifier:', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.00068962533>)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Layer weight regularizers](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/), you must subclass tensorflow.keras.regularizers.Regularizer if you want your regularizer to take additional parameters beyond the layer's weight tensor.

And it also looks like you are trying to support serialization, so don't forget to add the `get_config` method.

```
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package='Custom', name='esgd')
class ESGD(regularizers.Regularizer):

    def __init__(self, mu):
        self.mu = mu

    def __call__(self, w):
        return (mu/2) * tf.math.square(tf.norm(w - tf.transpose(w)))

    def get_config(self):
        return {'mu': self.mu}
```

and then you can use it with

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='ones', kernel_regularizer=ESGD(mu=mu))
```